Recoloring bootstrap checkbox buttons & missing hover behavior
I'm trying to change to color of a bootstrap 5 btn-outline-primary button. See https://jsfiddle.net/nct2dpvf/17/ for an example.

The standard button (with class btn-outline-primary in the example) does not change color when hovering, even though it does in the example at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#outlined-styles. I'm using the exact same structure and classes.
The re-colored button (Red only) uses custom CSS btn-red, and is ok when hovering, but does not change color when clicked on (while the Outline only button does)
If I combine both btn-red and btn-outline-primary, hovering works, but the background turns blue when clicked on.

How can I get hovering to work for the standard button (btn-outline-primary) and have a red color when checked on the red button (btn-outline-danger)?

Your code must be included in the question itself. Please read [ask] even though as a 12+ years long member, you should be well aware of that.

When I go into your code, and I remove your resources

And then paste the Bootstrap 5 library cdn links:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/
It begins to work, I think you're not including the version of JS and Bootstrap that the class requires. The documentation you've linked is for bootstrap 5 and requires the JS to operate too.
EDIT:
Seems the red button does not work either, here's the code for that:
.btn-red:hover, .btn-check:checked + .btn-red{
    border-color: #d67272 !important;
    background-color: #d67272 !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}


Thanks! This fixes the hover for the Outline only button, but not the color of the red button when clicked. Any idea what goes wrong there?

Yeah I do! It's because it's not btn-red, it's btn-danger, the colour is called danger not red it will be in the documentation if you'd like to look further. Also please mark me as the answer and upvote since this was helpful :D

btn-red uses a custom color #d67272 (which needs to be flexible to change), which is specified in the CSS of the fiddle. I can't use the fixed btn-danger color. So my question is how can I use a custom color and still have the the behavior of a btn-outline-primary (when hovering and selected)?

why not write your own css code on hover? and just have that as your own custom class with a hover css tag? it would be easier to customise too!

That's what I've done :-) See the CSS section of the fiddle, also copied below. While the hover is working, it doesn't change color when clicked (which does work for the standard btn-outline-primary).
.btn-red {
border-color: #d67272 !important;
color: #d67272 !important;
}
.btn-red:hover, .btn-red:active, .btn-red + .btn-check:checked {
border-color: #d67272 !important;
background-color: #d67272 !important;
color: #ffffff !important;
}

Use this instead:
.btn-red:hover, .btn-check:checked + .btn-red{
border-color: #d67272 !important;
background-color: #d67272 !important;
color: #ffffff !important;
}
The code is also in my edit.
